# Creating custom html thumbnails for cms pages - i.e. news section using title and a custom field image

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

Basically am wondering is if there is a way to use magento as an actual cms system.

i.e. i have an html chunk (static block?!) with some parameters (page_image, pagetitle)

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="[page_image]" />
    <p>[pagetitle]</p>
</div>
```

I would like to loop through a set of cms pages, and print a thumbnail section with that information.

I am a complete newbie to magento, and i cant figure this out with just the basics i learned through the tutorials xd.

**What am actually asking** are a few points:

1. **How** can i create custom fields for specific cms-pages?
2. **How** can i loop through those specific cms-pages and print a thumbnail sort of view

*links to tutorials are much appreciated!*

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom fields for Magento CMS page section, you can follow below links
https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/ 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53094/2443 
To display CMS pages as thumbnail view, you can use below code.

```
$cmsPages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
foreach ($cmsPages as $cmsPage){
     echo $cmsPage->getTitle();
     .. GET AND DISPLAY YOUR REQUIRED DETAILS ..
}
```

**Edited:** 
To loop through the specific cms Pages,
You can use `addFieldToFilter` for filtering. like,

```
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()>addFieldToFilter‌​('YOUR_FIELD_NAME', 'YOUR_FILTER_VALUE')
```

[reference](http://www.seanbreeden.com/stackoverflow-magento-addfieldtofilter/)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and let you know. Can i somehow filter my cms-pages i want to show in that `Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
 `?

Comment: You can use `addFieldToFilter` for filtering. like, `Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()>addFieldToFilter(''YOUR_FIELD_NAME', 'YOUR_FILTER_VALUE')` reference http://www.seanbreeden.com/stackoverflow-magento-addfieldtofilter/

Comment: sorry to ask so many questions, but am a complete newbie! Where do i put the code with the foreach loop you gave me? i will create a layout for the page i want the thumbs to be in, and put it there?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you have to put it in your `phtml` file where you are going to add your page's html code.

Comment: hey man i did everything in the atwix tutorial and although i get the new field to show on the cms page, the value is not stored! I dont know what i missed, if you have some previous experience with some details i might have missed please let me know, i did this tutorial 3 times!

Comment: Can you update you question with your code. It will be easier that way to find any issue.

Comment: I updated it, for some reason i cant get code styling to work ;/, but its the same with atwix with only minor changes in nameing. i also tried 100% the code from atwix, and also could not save. 
When the installer is run, should a new column appear in cms_page table?

Comment: nevermind it worked! i added the extra column manually.. is this normal? shouldnt install.php add it?